# How to create webdriver in multithreaded environment using runnable interface

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

Need to implement WebDriver in multithreaded environment so each of my test case will initiate its own thread while parallel execution. Tried with `ThreadLocal` concept but it did not solved the issue. Test cases are failing randomly due to element not visible and timeout exception.

Comment: what framework you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I would say not to manage the threads yourself as it is not easy and very difficult to manage. Instead use a framework like [testNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

TestNG supports parallel execution using multiple threads in the class/methods/test level

```
<suite name="My suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">

<suite name="My suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">

<suite name="My suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">

<suite name="My suite" parallel="instances" thread-count="5">
```

Comment: I am using TestNG. After searching on internet I found Webdriver is not Thread safe so was trying to find out other approaches

Comment: @AjayShinde, It depends on your test design. Check this example for webdriver testng design  - http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-design-tests-test-data/